# AuthorizeAttribute redirects to access denied page even if logged

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

Startup.cs:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "CustomAuthenticationCookieMiddleware",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/user/login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/user/logout"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/access-denied"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });
```

MembershipController.cs

```
...
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("CustomAuthenticationCookieMiddleware", claimsPrincipal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = loginUser.RememberMe });
...
```

========

PROBLEM:

`[Authorize]` Attribute does not work. It redirects to access-denied page.

BUT  `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` works very well

NOTE:  `"User.Identity.IsAuthenticated"` is always false even if I successfully login

Comment: Do you use `UseIdentity()` or another authentication middleware before `UseCookieAuthentication` in your `Configure` method ?

Comment: no just use above code

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET default authentication mechanism or using custom authentication? You have any custom `Authorize` attribute in your project?

Comment: custom authentication. But I dont use any custom Authorize attribte

Comment: I think posted code works well. Can you post Startup.cs and Controller code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quoting:

> Similarly, for the Forbidden response, the user is redirected to the
>   path specified in AccessDeniedPath when we added the middleware to our
>   pipeline. We don't redirect to the login path in this case, as the
>   user is already authenticated, they just don't have the correct claims
>   or permissions to view the requested resource

Read this excellent article and solve your problem: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-cookieauthenticationmiddleware-in-asp-net-core/